# Firebase Sorting Data Alphabetically

Tags: objective-c, firebase

How do I sort my data alphabetically with objective-C. I'm seeing some basic stuff in the documentation about using priorities and sorting by key values but not seeing much for sorting the abcs.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries  Most likely you want to read the section "Ordering by value", but your question is a bit too broad to be certain.

Comment: Thanks this did it, the section with ordering the dinosaurs alphabetically.